# How can i bind data(ID ) from a webservice to 2 Radio buttons(0 and 1) on listview, expecting the result in json format in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

[Feedback image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqCHe.png)    // Class of data coming from webservice, each question with its own ID

```
     public class Class1
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string question { get; set; }
        }
```

// Class of the expected result that will produce the json format below

```
     public class Rootobject
        {
            public string description { get; set; }
            public Booking booking { get; set; }
            public int rating { get; set; }
            public Questionnaire[] questionnaire { get; set; }
        }
```

// Class of the answer from checkbox, i want to get the ID of the question and the value of the answer either 0 0r 1 when selecting each of the text box. i dont want any question to be left unanswered

```
    public class Questionnaire
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int answer { get; set; }
        }
```

// My xaml code, but i haven't bind the ID to the radio buttons

```
    <ListView Margin="10,0,10,20" Background="White" x:Name="feedbackListView">

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Rootobject">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding question}"></TextBlock>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <RadioButton Foreground="Green" Name="ServiceYes" Content="Yes" GroupName="services" Checked="Exposure_Checked"></RadioButton>
                                    <RadioButton Foreground="Red" Name="ServiceNo" Content="No" GroupName="services" Checked="Exposure_Checked"></RadioButton>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListView>
```

// Method for getting my data from the webservice, the question and the id

```
    async void getData()
            {

                string url = "http://10.91.91.50:7500/NNRAService/webresources/customerResources/getQuestionaire";
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
                var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JsonArray root = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetArray();
                for (uint i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
                {
                    string Question = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("question");
                    string Id = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedNumber("id").ToString();
                    var chan = new Class1
                    {
                        question = Question,
                        id = Id,

                    };
                    feedbackList.Add(chan);


                };
                feedbackListView.ItemsSource = feedbackList;

            }
```

// Expected result after clicking submit button, the result would be in json format

```
{
  "description": "desc",
 "booking":{"id": "Ref_id"},
 "rating": 2,
 "questionnaire":[{"id":1,"answer":0}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To bind int to the `IsChecked` property `RadioButton`, we should be able to `Converter`. We can create a converter by implementing the [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding#properties_) interface and implementing the Convert method.

For example:

```
class IntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // Retrieve the format string and use it to format the value.
        int votenumber, currentone;
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            votenumber = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
            currentone = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);

            if (votenumber == currentone)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int  currentone;
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            currentone = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
            if (currentone==0)
            {
                return currentone;
            }
            else
            {
               return currentone;   
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To bind the same id to the different `IsChecked` property of the RadioButton, we should be able to use ValueConverter with ConverterParamater to achieve it.

The XAML code:

```
<ListView Margin="10,0,10,20" Background="White" x:Name="feedbackListView">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:IntConverter x:Key="IntToBoolConverter" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding question}"></TextBlock>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <RadioButton Foreground="Green" Name="ServiceYes" Content="Yes" GroupName="{Binding question}" Checked="Exposure_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding id,Mode=TwoWay,ConverterParameter=0,Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter}}"></RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Foreground="Red" Name="ServiceNo" Content="No" GroupName="{Binding question}" Checked="Exposure_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding id,Mode=TwoWay,ConverterParameter=1,Converter={StaticResource IntToBoolConverter}}"></RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You should be able to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the Class1.

For example:

```
public class Class1: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private int _id;
    private string _question;

    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("id");
        }
    }

    public string question
    {
        get { return _question; }
        set
        {
            _question = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("question");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, we should be able to set the different `GroupName` of one group `RadioButton`. If we set the same name to the `GroupName` to the all `RadioButton`, only one `RadioButton` can be checked.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but not clear enough. I've attached the expecting UI image above "Feedback image" you can check the image for further clarification. i'm expecting something like this as a result "questionnaire":[{"id":1,"answer":0},{"id":2,"answer":1},{"id":3,"answer":0},{"id":4,"answer":1}]. Both radio buttons must have common ID, only the value should be different if Yes or No is selected

Comment: How does the IntConverter class works with my own request

Comment: @OlayemiRondo We can bind  id to the `GroupName` and bind answer to `IsChecked`. We can send `ConverterParameter` to the `IntConverter`. When the answer is 0, the `IntConverter` will return true to `ServiceYes` and return false to `ServiceNo`.

Comment: Thanks, i will be very grateful if i can get both code for xaml and backend sir. Don't forget that i'm working with list view and i will be sending both ID and answer (0 or 1) to a json array

Comment: Do you mean the user can select the RadioButton and save it to the json array? If so, you should be able to use the two way binding for the IsChecked and you need to implement ConvertBack method.

Comment: I don't know how to go with two way binding and convertBack, i've worked with checkbox before and i never used two way binding. you can show me the code or u should check the new trend i just created now that shows my progress

Comment: Are u talking about your solution? you can check the new trend i just created for my progress. The Class1 class is just a model class for what i'm getting from the service

Comment: @OlayemiRondo It is my solution for save the `Checked` to Class1. If you want set the Class1 data to json, it is a new question. You should be able to open a new question.

Comment: i'm not saving the checked to class1 class, i'm saving it to Questionaire Class

Comment: You should be able implement the INotifyPropertyChanged for the `Questionnaire`. When you change the selected `RadioButton`, the `answer` property will changed.

Comment: I've gotten breakthrough here you can check this trend "How can i replace the value of checked radio button from a LIST whenever i change my option from yes to no vice versa in UWP". check it if I use the right method

Comment: If you want use `Checked` event, it is right. You can also use the binding.

Comment: Thanks for you time, may God bless you